# Loop in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to add pairs of keys and values to the result(of a row), so I did like this:

```
      row :skill_level do |user|
        level = {}
        user.try(:sport_memberships).each do |sport|
          sport_name  = Sport.where(id: sport.try(:sport_id)).try(:name)
          sport_level = sport.try(:level)
          level       = level.merge!("#{sport_name.to_sym}" => sport_level)
        end
      end
```

The association of models is:
user.rb

```
has_many :sport_memberships,
           inverse_of: "user",
           class_name: "Sport::Membership"
```

sport.rb

```
has_many :memberships
```

membership.rb

```
belongs_to :sport, inverse_of: "memberships", counter_cache: true
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: "sport_memberships"
```

I expected the level will return value like: {badminton: 2, golf: 2}, but the actual rerults is: `[#<Sport::Membership id: 5024, sport_id: 4, user_id: 976, level: 2, tribe_id: nil>, #<Sport::Membership id: 5025, sport_id: 14, user_id: 976, level: 2, tribe_id: nil>]`. It seems my loop didn't run as my expectation. How can I fix my problem?

Comment: You should try group by query instead of this loop

Comment: Can you please add association of user, sport, sport_memberships in question ?

Comment: @Vishal, I updated

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to build a hash, you could do that so:

```
row :skill_level do |user|
  user.sport_memberships.each_with_object({}) do |mem,hsh|
    hsh[mem.sport.name] = mem.sport.level
  end.to_s
end
```

However, you could also build a string like so:

```
row :skill_level do |user|
  user.sport_memberships.map do |mem|
    "#{mem.sport.name}: #{mem.sport.level}"
  end.join(", ")
end
```

Optionally, to get better index performance add the following to your registration:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    super.include(sports_memberships: [:sports])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all override the controller action

**Not tested**

```
 def index 
   super
   @levels = User.joins(sport_memberships: :sport).where(id: resource.id).select("sports.name, sport_memberships.level").group("sports.name, sport_memberships.level")
 end
```

Please try this query let me know if its working or not.

Comment: it returned User class name

Comment: try to map attributes `User.joins(sport_memberships: :sport).where(id: resource.id).select("sports.name, sport_memberships.level").group("sports.name, sport_memberships.level").map(&:attributes)`